# How do I add the median and average to a graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have this graph which was composed from a dataset. I want to add a horizontal line at the Median (0.97), and a separate horizontal line at the Average (1.16). I need the horizontal lines to reference the cells where the Mean and Median are calculated. Hoping someone can help me do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple approaches to tackle this issue and it depends a bit on how you want the final plot to look like.

**Approach 1: Helper Column**

The potentially easier solution is to simply add an extra column to your data with, e.g., the mean value for which you want to have the horizontal line. Assuming your regular data is stored in the range `A1:A11` and the addition of the values for the horizontal line in column `B` (these values can of course link to your computations of the e.g., the mean):

| values | H1 |
| --- | --- |
| -10 | 5 |
| -7.5 | 5 |
| -5 | 5 |
| -2.5 | 5 |
| -1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2.5 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 7.5 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 |

Select the data -> `Insert` -> `Clusterd Column Chart`. Next select your Chart -> `Chart Design` -> `Change Chart Type` -> `Combo` -> Change the H1 chart type to `Line`.

This will return the following chart:

[image: chart1]

---

**Approach 2: Helper Table**

Another approach is using a helper table that stores the information for the horizontal line, e.g., in the range `D1:E3`:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | -5 |
| 10.5 | -5 |

Select now your values in column `A` and the x value in column `C` -> `Insert` -> `Recommended Charts` -> `Combo` -> values to `Clustered Column` and x to `XY Scatter with Smooth Lines`. Next, select the chart -> `Chart Design` -> `Select Data` -> `Select x` -> `Edit` -> select x and y values according to your helper table.

This will return the following chart:

[image: chart2]

The main benefit of this slightly more complex approach is that you can better tailor the length of the horizontal line.

---

The names in the legends for the helper columns can be changed accordingly. The same goes for adding additional horizontal lines.

Comment: I went with the first option, it turned out well, thankyou!